# Cannot dereference double pointer, " no match for operator* "

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, dereference, double-pointer

I'm trying to search through an array of pointers to objects of class Shape. I have written the following code. However, I'm getting this error: "no match for operator*", and I don't know where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

```
Shape** shapesArray;

bool doesNameExist(string name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < shapeCount; i++)
    {
        if(*(shapesArray[i])->getName() == name)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `[i]`does first dereference. `->` does second dereference. `*` is trying to dereference what is returned by `getName()`.

Comment: Please explain what you think that `if(*(shapesArray[i])->getName() == name)` does.

Comment: use `std::array` or `std::vector` if want to avoid such headaces

Comment: Also returning in the first iteration of the loop regardless of the result of judge looks weird.

Comment: Try to use one more parenthesis with dot operator. Maybe it helps like this statement
`if((*(shapesArray[i])).getName() == name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `shapesArray` is a `Shape**`
- `shapesArray[i]` is `Shape*`
- `(shapesArray[i])->getName()` is dereferencing `shapesArray[i]` and calls its
  member `getName`

So far nothing wrong. I guess this is what you actually want to get, but you add another `*`:

- `*(shapesArray[i])->getName()` tries to dereference what was returned from `getName` (a `std::string` perhaps?)

PS: You return from the loop in the first iteration in either case. If you want to search in the array you need to loop until you find it (then `return true`) or loop till the end (then `return false` after the loop, because it wasn't found).